# code coverage for Jenkins shared Groovy library with jacoco

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a [shared groovy library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) that provides some steps (in vars folder) for a Jenkins pipeline.
For the steps I have groovy unit tests in place and want to calculate code coverage with them. I already have setup jacoco successfully and get coverage results for my objects (in src folder). 
However, jacoco is not calculating the coverage for the steps, because they are not on the class path.

Any idea how to get the coverage for this steps? Anyone who has experience with this?

Comment: It is disturbing that a CI/CD system does not supply this for itself.